# shell script does not find the directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm starting in the shell script.I'm need to make the checksum of a lot of files, so I thought to automate the process using an shell script.
I make to scripts: the first script uses an recursive *ls* command with an *egrep -v* that receive as parameter the path of file inputed by me, these command is saved in a ambient variable that converts the output in a string, follow by a loop(for) that cut the output's string in lines and pass these lines as a parameter when calling the second script; The second script take this parameter and pass they as parameter to *hashdeep* command,wich in turn is saved in another ambient variable that, as in previous script,convert the output's command in a string and cut they using IFS,lastly I'm take the line of interest and put then in a text file.

The output is:

> /home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/2016-10-27-001757.jpg: No such file
>   or directory
>
> ----Checksum FILE: 2016-10-27-001757.jpg
>   ----Checksum HASH:

the issue is: I sets as parameter the directory *~/Pictures* but in the output error they return another directory,/*home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/*(the own directory), in this case, the file *2016-10-27-001757.jpg* is in the *~/Pictures* directory,why the script is going in its own directory?

First script:

```
#/bin/bash                                                      

arquivos=$(ls -R $1 | egrep -v '^d')

for linha in $arquivos
        do
                bash ./task2.sh $linha
        done
```

second script:

```
#/bin/bash                                              

checksum=$(hashdeep $1)
concatenado=''

for i in $checksum
        do
                concatenado+=$i

        done

IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$concatenado"

echo
echo '----Checksum FILE:' $1
echo '----Checksum HASH:' ${ADDR[4]}
echo
echo ${ADDR[4]} >> ~/Trampo/shell_scripts/txt2.txt
```

I think that's...sorry about the English grammatic errors.
I hope that the question has become clear.
Thanks ins advanced!

Comment: Run your script though http://shellcheck.net and post again when you have fixed all errors :-)

Comment: Small sample inputs and required output (included in the body of the Q) eliminate many issues about defining the problem with language ;-). Can you please add some to your Q? Good luck.

Comment: It is better to use `find` than parsing the output of `ls`. You can rewrite the first script as `find $1 -type f -exec ./task2.sh {} \;` or if you like `xargs`, `find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ./task2.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several wrong in the first script alone.

When running `ls` in recursive mode using `-R`, the output is listed per directory and each file is listed relative to their parent instead of full pathname.

`ls -R` doesn't list the directory in long format as implied by `| grep -v ^d` where it seems you are looking for files (non directories).

In your specific case, the missing file `2016-10-27-001757.jpg` is in a subdirectory but you lost the location by using `ls -R`.

Do not parse the output of `ls`. Use `find` and you won't have the same issue.

First script can be replaced by a single line.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type f -exec ./task2.sh "{}" \;
```

Or if you prefer using `xargs`, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} ./task2.sh "{}"
```

Note: enclosing `{}` in quotes ensures that `task2.sh` receives a complete filename even if it contains spaces.

In `task2.sh` the parameter `$1` should also be quoted `"$1"`.

If `task2.sh` is executable, you are all set. If not, add `bash` in the line so it reads as:

```
find $1 -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh "{}" \;
```

`task2.sh`, though not posted in the original question, is not executable. It has a missing `execute` permission.

Add execute permission to it by running `chmod` like:

```
chmod a+x task2.sh
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Where I must put this line exactly? Thanks

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva - I updated the answer to show that the contents of first script can be replaced by the one line in here.

Comment: I put both of lines in the place of the line "arquivos=$(ls -R $1 | egrep -v '^d')" : "arquivos=$(find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ./task2.sh)" and "arquivos=$(find $1 -type f -exec ./task2.sh {} \;)" and the output returns "find: "./task2.sh":permission dined" =(

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Get rid of everything. The file should only have this line.

Comment: I make a new script with only the line you tell me but de output returns 'permission dined' yet..

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva - did you read my update regarding execute permission on `task2.sh`?

Comment: The same error yet "permission dined"...I tested the both scripts but did not work

Comment: You are getting permission denied because test2.sh is not executable. It should be a separate issue but I'll update my answer.

Comment: i try run the line "find $1 -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh {} \;" its works partially..the output is like that:/home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/desafios: No such file or directory

/home/douglas/Trampo/shell_scripts/Firefox_003.png: No such file or directory

----Checksum FILE: /home/douglas/Imagens/Geotecnologia: tendências e desafios - Mozilla Firefox_003.png
----Checksum HASH:


----Checksum FILE: /home/douglas/Imagens/Webcam/2016-10-27-001757.jpg
----Checksum HASH: 40c760ff07c60b6a37d279ecdeab26b8

Comment: I have a feeling your filenames have spaces and non-printable characters. I updated my answer to accommodate it.

Comment: So dude...i actualized the first and second lines as your recommends,and did not works to...but third line (find $1 -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh "{}" \;) works good if I do not pass an parameter,if I try set an directory this works partially returning the output like I paste in the my comment above...

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva - If you are saying the first 2 didn't work but the third works, you are doing everything wrong. The first and third is exactly the same command, why would they differ in your script? Your second script, `task2.sh`, is wrong. You should quote `$1` to preserve the spaces in filename.

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva - The only thing this is possible is if `task2.sh` is not executable. This means you never read my answer.

Comment: pluse-uno for good answer + tech support ;-). Good luck to all.

Comment: @alvits I have one more question: about the "{}" you said it is for the script receive the file names with contain space characters, but to me it don't works. He it interprets space as the end of the name/star of the name and not find the files...why I'm doing wrong?  (My code is exactly as yours)...Thanks!